# Angular code is not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularJs, twitter bootstrap with asp.net mvc4. I didn't use angular-strap. I am trying to load a partial view in bootstrap modal. The partial view contains angular code.

**Here is my code where I am calling the bootstrap modal:**

```
@model IEnumerable<IMS.Domain.Model.GetAllRequisitions_Result>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Requisition List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPage.cshtml";
}

<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalluncher" data-toggle="modal" onclick="loadCreateForm()"> Launch demo modal </a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCreateForm() {
        var content = '@Url.Action("Create", "Requisition", new { area = "IMS" })';
        $('div.modal-body').load(content);
}
</script>
```

**Here is my code for 'Create' action of 'Requisition' controller:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>

<div ng-app="">
    <label>Sample: <input type="text" ng-model="sample" /></label>
    <br />
    <label>Show Value: {{sample}}</label>
</div>

<div class="ContainerRowButton">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

**For ng-model="sample" when I am trying to show data by {{sample}} it stays {{sample}}. It's like my 'Create' action is not getting angularJs.**

**I've rendered all necessary scrips in the 'MasterPage.cshtml'. My MasterPage.cshtml contains:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/others")
```

**And here is the code of my 'Bundle.config.cs' file:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/others").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/dataTables_bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Custom/CustomScript.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js"
                    ));
```

What wrong am I doing? Need help ...

Comment: What does `loadCreateForm()` do?  Are you loading in the partial with an ajax call?

Comment: You are injecting your modal html after page load has been completed and your modal html is not bound to $scope. your need to compile your html with `$compile(html)($scope)` for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what @Muctadir said, you need to tell angular to check your modal partial for angular elements.  You do that by calling `$compile` before injecting the partial into the DOM.  The problem is that you have to be able to get access to the `$compile` service and you can't do that inside of your `loadCreateForm()`, you can only do that from an angular module.  So, you need to organize your code in such a way that you can get what you need.  Here's my suggestion:

Create a directive to handle your modal and its contents:

```
.directive('myModal', function($compile){
    return {
        replace:false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var content = '@Url.Action("Create", "Requisition", new { area = "IMS" })';
            elem.load(content, null, function(){
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

That will load the content and then compile the contents using the current scope, but only after the content has been loaded from the server.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please post the full code ? I am missing something, I have the same problem & cannot make it work in any way.